# a4j:poll - reloading data model

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm trying to use `a4j:poll` component for ajax reloading a datatable after some time interval. It's working fine, but when the table is automatically reloaded and I use the tools (edit/delete row) in the last column, datatable (all the rows) disappears and I have to load it manually (using `h:commandButton`)..

Here's part of my code:

```
<h:form>
  <a4j:poll id="poll" interval="30000" action="#{bean.load}" enabled="#{bean.pollEnabled}" render="list" />
</h:form>

<h:form id="list" ...>
 <rich:dataTable id="table" var="item" value="#{bean.model}">
 ...
```

A button which is calling the same load method:

```
  <h:commandButton id="btn" action="#{bean.load}" ... />
```

When I reload it using button, I can use the tools in the last column. Don't you know why?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

- seems that in first case (`a4j:poll`), when using edit/delete, constructor of the bean is called........
- bean is `@ViewScoped`

Comment: What if you put them in the same form?

Comment: You're really the greatest!:-) Thanks, it works. Please create an answer to accept it

Comment: Okay, I reposted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *seems that in first case (a4j:poll), when using edit/delete, constructor of the bean is called*

I don't do RichFaces, but I *guess* that this problem is in some way related to [JSF issue 790](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-790) which causes the view state of other forms being lost during ajax requests initiated by a separate form (and indeed also causes reconstruction of the backing beans associated with the other forms). This is also described as point 7 of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183).

In your particular case, placing the `<a4j:poll>` in the same form as the table should solve the problem. I'm not sure why that was placed in a separate form in first place, but that seems just unnecessary.

Comment: It was separated because it's reloading two separated forms (in real application). So I've thought it would be better to be separeted too :-) Anyway, it works much better inside a form, thanks again :-)